# Definite or indefinite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

If a functions say f(x) is to be integrated from the limits -infinity to +infinity .

Will this integral be categorized as a definite integral or indefinite integral?

Comment: definite and improper. indefinite would be finding its antiderivative.

Comment: It is called an "improper" definite integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Indefinite integral" is a really poor terminology, which is unfortunately very widespread.

In any case, what is usually meant by "indefinite integral" is what should be called "antiderivative".

What is often called "definite integral", and should be called just "integral", is the number obtained as the limit of the Riemann sums. One then pushes this terminology a bit for improper integrals, which are limits of integrals: when we write $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$, we really mean 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^Nf(x),dx
$$
(and there could actually be a second limit if $f(x)$ is not defined at $0$.

When the limits are $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, also two limits (beyond the one defining the integral) are involved:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx :=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-N}^0f(x)\,dx+\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx.
$$